# Onscreen keyboard keeps popping up - Ubunto 20.04

Tags: keyboard, touchscreen, onscreen-keyboard

Since an update about 2/3 weeks ago, every time I touch the screen of my laptop the onboard keyboard annoyingly pops up. I was hoping this issue would get solved with new updates but since it is not the case I've decided to ask for help.
The keyboard is disabled in the universal access settings and it is not a hidden startup application.
I really do not want it to appear at all, how could I disable it? Is anyone else having this problem? I have not been able to find an answer just by searching online.
I'm using a Acer Aspire V.

Comment: Same on Yoga Y720. There are numerous bugs about this, all closed. I think it is a problem with Gnome that's out of Ubuntu's control or something.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a Gnome extension called `Block Caribou` before to successfully block the screen keyboard. This is the latest version:

[Block Caribou 36 Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3222/block-caribou-36/)

Comment: Hi Codlord!
The extension works perfectly! Thanks very much!!!

Comment: Same issue. The Caribou extension works in chrome but not outside, like in terminal window. Any other solution for this?