# On-screen Keyboard

Tags: 20.04, keyboard

Is it possible to disable the virtual keyboard.  It automatically pops up when I get to the login screen or when I touch the screen on my laptop.

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 64-bit
Lenovo-FLEX-3-1120

Comment: Des [this reference](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/gh0t8t/disableignore_touchscreen_on_ubuntu_2004/) help?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

search for screen-keyboard and disable it

Comment: . (use caution, do a backup first)  others from my notes gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.applications screen-keyboard-enabled true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.applications screen-keyboard-enabled false
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261743/onscreen-keyboard-keeps-popping-up-ubunto-20-04
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3222/block-caribou-36/